# Diagonal Difference Hacker Rank kotlin Minha solução aprova em alguns mas reprova no resto

Tags: algoritmo, lógica, kotlin

```kotlin
   fun diagonalDifference(arr: Array<Array<Int>>): Int {
     var tamanho = arr.size - 1
     var i = 0
     var diagonal1 = 0
     var diagonal2 = 0

     for(i in 0 .. tamanho){
        diagonal1 += arr[i][i]
        diagonal2 += arr[i][tamanho - i]
     }
    
     return diagonal2.minus(diagonal1)
    }

   fun main(args: Array<String>) {
     val n = readLine()!!.trim().toInt()

     val arr = Array<Array<Int>>(n, { Array<Int>(n, { 0 }) })

     for (i in 0 until n) {
        arr[i] = readLine()!!.trimEnd().split(" ").map{ it.toInt() }.toTypedArray()
     }

     val result = diagonalDifference(arr)

     println(result)
    }
```

Nesta minha solução no Hacker Rank é aprovada em 4 casos mas rejeitada em 6. Eu ja não sei mais oque mudar, sou iniciante e gostaria de uma ajuda se for possível.

Comment: Coloque o prefixo do desafio e os valores de que eles esperam que seu programe retorne (os testes que deve passar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abri aqui o hackerrank e acredito que você deixou passar um detalhe, a questão pede que seja retornado um `numero absoluto`, ou seja, um numero sempre positivo, mas dependendo do input, o seu resultado pode gerar números negativos caso a diagonal2 seja menor que a diagonal1. Uma forma simples de corrigir seria chamando o Math.abs. Por exemplo:

```
fun diagonalDifference(arr: Array<Array<Int>>): Int {
var tamanho = arr.size - 1
var i = 0
var diagonal1 = 0
var diagonal2 = 0

for(i in 0 .. tamanho){
    diagonal1 += arr[i][i]
    diagonal2 += arr[i][tamanho - i]
}

return Math.abs(diagonal2.minus(diagonal1)) //vai retornar sempre positivo agora

}
```

Comment: Po Lucas muito obrigado, eu já não sabia mais pra qual lado correr, estava pensando q alguma coisa na minha lógica tava errada. Resolveu mesmo, passou batido isso aí de ser somente resultados positivos.